# How to backup or script all the Synonyms of the database in SSMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssms-2017

How to backup or script all the Synonyms of the database in SSMS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click your database in the object Explorer, and select "Tasks" -> "Generate Scripts...". On the Choose Objects window, select the "Select specific database objects" and tick "Synonyms" (like below):

[image]

Choose whether you want to save file to disc, clipboard or a new query window. Click Next and the next.

Done.